# Problems with UTF-8 representation of nbsp in XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, utf-8

I am having various issues with XSL using the UTF-8 byte code representation of `&nbsp;`. I'm using Saxon HE9.5.1.4

The input files is a HTML file converted to XHTML using tidy. It's UTF-8 and contains the byte sequence 0xC2 0xA0, which I verified by using hex mode in EMACS. Viewing the HTML file in EMACS displays the character pair as a grey (not black) underscore. It shows up as a space viewing the file in a browser (Firefox or Chrome).

The XSLT uses `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`. This eliminates `&nbsp` but leaves `c2a0` intact. What could I be doing that would cause this behavior? To by understanding both should be removed by the XSLT processor before my transform is executed.

I've also tried to filter these characters in my XSLT, but I am having problems representing them. In XPATH I can use `"thing[text()='_'"]`, where the _ is copied from the XHTML file using EMACS, and it works. I find this too fragile since it is not obvious that these are not normal underscore characters. I tried to use `thing[text()=codepoints-to-string((194, 160))]` but it did not match anything. `(194, 160)` is the decimal byte pair for 0xC2 0xA0.

So this unusual byte sequence is acting strangely in XSLT files. Anyone run into this before and know what to do?

Comment: maybe do a replace of these chars before sending file to XSL??

Comment: Does your XHTML you feed to Saxon have an XML declaration declaring the encoding? Saxon simply uses an underlying XML parser so inside your XSLT you are dealing with Unicode characters and not with UTF-8 byte sequences, hence any comparison should be e.g. `match="foo[. = '&#160;']"` or `match="foo[. = codepoints-to-string(160)]"` if you really think you need that. And I don't understand why you think that a non breaking space would be stripped by "strip-space", the characters defined to make up a white space text node are defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-whitespace-text-node.

Comment: You point out a possibility that i had not considered. I do declare the HTML to be in UTF-8. The question is what codepoint Saxon uses. Do you know how it deals with mullti-byte UTF-8 characters. That's another way of asking if the 0xC2 0xA0 byte sequence is mapped to the same thing as &nbsp; If it was that would explain why I am not able to match the two byte sequence.

Comment: XSLT/XPath/XQuery strings are sequences of Unicode letters, the input encoding does not matter inside your XSLT code. If you have an input document with a certain encoding declared properly to the XML parser the XSLT processor uses then all should be fine, as long as you understand that inside your XSLT you deal with strings as sequences of Unicode characters. As for the HTML to be declared in UTF-8, I don't know whether Tidy adds an XML declaration when converting to XHTML. But on the other hand UTF-8 is the default encoding an XML parser works with.